# Lookup Function in Excel returning First Result instead of Closest Match

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

I've been using the following code to perform rough lookups in Excel. The code lets you find approximate matches between a lookup value and a table of strings. For instance, it would be able to match "JS Smith" to "John JS Smith", "Fifth Street West" to "5th Street West", etc. The code is as follows:

```
Function FuzzyFind(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant
For Each cell In tbl_array
  str = cell
  For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
    If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
      a = a + 1
      cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid(cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
    End If
  Next i
  a = a - Len(cell)
  If a > b Then
    b = a
    Value = str
  End If
  a = 0
Next cell
FuzzyFind = Value
End Function
```

Generally it works pretty well. The problem with this code is it seems to always return the first value that it finds in the table, rather than the closest match. I suspect it could be improved by getting it to loop through the table, but I can't seem to make the syntax work. I also would like to put in a minimum string value for a match so that it is blank if the match is not close enoguh.

How can I change this code so that it returns the closest result instead of the first, and input a minimum value so that it doesn't return inaccurate matches?

Comment: How are you defining "closest match"? I think that any good solution would need to involve a computation of Levenshtein distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance , although perhaps something like this is what you have in mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Can you show an example where it does not find the "closest match" because I don't see that it always finds the first match. Actually it does loop through the range to find the "closest". And in my short tests it always found the closest out of a similar group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's interesting.  Perhaps you could return an array from the function and put it into a dropdown box for the user to choose from.  Try this list in your range and try the tester sub below.

```
Function FuzzyFind(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As Variant

Dim i As Integer, str As String,
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, x as integer
Dim callingStringArray, matchArray() As Variant
Dim myArray() As Variant, arrayCounter As Long    

    Do While InStr(1, lookup_value, "  ")
        lookup_value = Replace(lookup_value, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    lookup_value = Trim(lookup_value)

    callingStringArray = Split(lookup_value)
    ReDim matchArray(1 To 1)
    arrayCounter = 1
    a = 0
    b = 1
    X = 2

'   For exact match it woulkd return only this string
If UBound(callingStringArray) > 1 Then
    With tbl_array
        Set c = .Find(callingStringArray(a) & " " & callingStringArray(b), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    ReDim Preserve matchArray(1 To arrayCounter)
                    matchArray(arrayCounter) = c
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
    End With

    With tbl_array
    tempVar = (callingStringArray(b) & " " & callingStringArray(X))
        Set c = .Find((tempVar), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    ReDim Preserve matchArray(1 To arrayCounter)
                    matchArray(arrayCounter) = c
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
    End With

    With tbl_array
        Set c = .Find(callingStringArray(b) & " " & callingStringArray(a), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    ReDim Preserve matchArray(1 To arrayCounter)
                    matchArray(arrayCounter) = c
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
    End With

    With tbl_array
        Set c = .Find(callingStringArray(a) & " " & callingStringArray(X), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    ReDim Preserve matchArray(1 To arrayCounter)
                    matchArray(arrayCounter) = c
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
    End With

    With tbl_array
        Set c = .Find(callingStringArray(X) & " " & callingStringArray(a), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    ReDim Preserve matchArray(1 To arrayCounter)
                    matchArray(arrayCounter) = c
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
    End With
    With tbl_array
        Set c = .Find(callingStringArray(X) & " " & callingStringArray(b), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    ReDim Preserve matchArray(1 To arrayCounter)
                    matchArray(arrayCounter) = c
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
    End With

Else

    For i = LBound(callingStringArray) To UBound(callingStringArray)
        With tbl_array
            Set c = .Find(callingStringArray(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    ReDim Preserve matchArray(1 To arrayCounter)
                    matchArray(arrayCounter) = c
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With
    Next i


End If




FuzzyFind = matchArray()
End Function



Sub testere4sed()
Dim anotherArray As Variant

    anotherArray = FuzzyFind("Fifth Cat St.", Range("A1:A70"))
    For i = LBound(anotherArray) To UBound(anotherArray)
        Debug.Print anotherArray(i)
    Next I

    Debug.Print "***********************"

    anotherArray = FuzzyFind("    Cat  ", Range("A1:A70"))
    For i = LBound(anotherArray) To UBound(anotherArray)
       Debug.Print anotherArray(i)
    Next I

End Sub
```